# Image not centered with react-zoom-pan-pinch after switching images until button to switch images is clicked a second time

Tags: reactjs

**Issue**

I'm using the [react-zoom-pan-pinch](https://github.com/prc5/react-zoom-pan-pinch) library to provide zoom in/out, actual size and fit to screen functionality for an image viewer. The fit to screen code came from other [discussion threads](https://github.com/prc5/react-zoom-pan-pinch/issues/376#issuecomment-1617956270). No issues with these functions.

I have a button to switch the image (by updating state), but when I click it, the image is not centered. Even weirder, when I hit the button again it gets centered as expected.

**Steps to repro:**

1. Open the project in codesandbox with Firefox (project wouldn't work for me in Chrome or private FF window) - https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-framework-3nczs7?file=/src/App.js
2. Click the 'Image 2' button in the Browser preview

**Result:**

The image loads and fits the screen, but it is off centered. If you click the 'Image 2' button again it gets centered as expected.

Any ideas what's causing the issue?

Answer (score 1):

When inspecting the elements in the browser after switching the image I observed that the Transform CSS values wasn't being updated after the first click. To resolve the issue I changed the `key` attribute on the `TransformWrapper` element from: `{${containerWidth}x${containerHeight}}` to `{${containerWidth}x${containerHeight}x${imageNaturalWidth}x${imageNaturalHeight}}`